# Non-breaking space &nbsp; not working in Weblogic 14

Tags: html, weblogic, weblogic14c

I recently updated from **Weblogic 12** to **Weblogic 14** Server.

## Before update

All was working fine, and if requested an html containing `&nbsp;` whitespaces, the server was responding the page content **including** `&nbsp;`.

## After update

The server is responding the html page content, excluding `&nbsp;` whitespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting the `&nbsp;` occurrences with `&#160;` will solve the problem.